# How to use Firebase Swift Package Manager with multi custom Framework and app swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift-package-manager

I have a problem with Firebase because it’s duplicated in my app

I installed Firebase from Swift Package Manager in my custom framework A 
I  installed Firebase from Swift Package Manager in my custom framework B

I also installed firebase from Swift Package Manager in my app
The custom framework B uses the custom framework A and my app uses custom framework A and B.

What do I have to do to make sure that the class is not implemented in both because i have this error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FBLPromise HTTPBody]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: see discussion at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/8871